# A basic question on non-negativity of a function

Tags: calculus, functions

how to prove that $f(x) = 2x\sin(\frac{1}{x}) - \cos (\frac{1}{x}) + 2$ is positive when $x\in (0,1]$.

I can see that by plotting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try looking at when each of the terms is positive/negative over the given interval.  Then show that the positives have a larger absolute value than the negatives for any value in $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 2):

Look first at $x\ge \frac{1}{2}$. Then $\sin(1/x)$ is positive, so our function is positive.

Look next at $0\lt x\lt \frac{1}{2}$. Then $2x\lt 1$. Thus $2x\sin(1/x)\gt -1$, so again our function is positive.

Comment: nicholas: how do you justify the first line ?

Comment: If $1/2\le x\le 1$, then $1\le \frac{1}{x}\le 2$. But $\sin t$ is positive in the whole interval $0\lt t\lt \pi$, and therefore in particular in the interval $[1,2]$.